# How to identify String is encoded with Base64

Tags: java

I am encoding URL request parameters from string to Base64 string using encodeURIComponent() method and passing it to server.
Server side in servlet filter i am decoding it from Base64 to string using java.util.Base64.

I am not converting all the requests(request parameters). If the URL contains json request parameters than only I am encoding the request parameter.

Here my problem is I want to check the request parameters is encoded or not.

Can any one suggest me any method is available to identify request parameter is encoded or not.

Comment: plz accept/upvote the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `commons` method  [Base64.isBase64(String base64)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#isBase64-java.lang.String-).

It returns a boolean True/False if your string is base64 encoded/or not.

Comment: Wrong! `Tests a given String to see if it contains only valid characters within the Base64 alphabet. Currently the method treats whitespace as valid.` The following will prove my point `Base64.isBase64("NOT_BASE64"); //true`